# How to install Font in Android device using programing without Root?

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, android-fonts, android-typeface

I want to install custom font which is .ttf file in android device when my application start. Actually i need to install Gujarati font in my android device when i run my application. is it possible ? if yes then how? Thanks. I don't need typeface.. i want to install in system setting without root device

Comment: not possible because all font related folder in root directory. and root directory can not access without root.

Comment: but if You don´t include it in Your app, then nobody will have it if You release the app.....is this really that what You want?

Comment: if you read gujarati font then you can use apps. that can translate your selected text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no other way to install font from your application without root its possible only when you put shruti.ttf file into assert folder

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/verdana.ttf");  
textfield.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.BOLD);
```

Also you can set your font by Extending other control ex.TextView

```
public class TextViewWithFont extends TextView {
private int defaultDimension = 0;
private int TYPE_BOLD = 1;
private int TYPE_ITALIC = 2;
private int FONT_ARIAL = 1;
private int FONT_OPEN_SANS = 2;
private int fontType;
private int fontName;

public TextViewWithFont(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null, 0);
}
public TextViewWithFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs, 0);
}
public TextViewWithFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(attrs, defStyle);
}
private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    // Load attributes
    final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.font, defStyle, 0);
    fontName = a.getInt(R.styleable.font_name, defaultDimension);
    fontType = a.getInt(R.styleable.font_type, defaultDimension);
    a.recycle();
    MyApplication application = (MyApplication ) getContext().getApplicationContext();
    if (fontName == FONT_ARIAL) {
        setFontType(application .getArialFont());
    } else if (fontName == FONT_OPEN_SANS) {
        setFontType(application .getOpenSans());
    }
}
private void setFontType(Typeface font) {
    if (fontType == TYPE_BOLD) {
        setTypeface(font, Typeface.BOLD);
    } else if (fontType == TYPE_ITALIC) {
        setTypeface(font, Typeface.ITALIC);
    } else {
        setTypeface(font);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Shruti is a paid commercial font from Microsoft @ 800$ per Year - https://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/shruti